# Convert Json subobject to a HashMap with Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I would like to convert the `bpi` field of the following json string:

```
{
    "bpi": {
        "2017-10-15": 5697.3917,
        "2017-10-16": 5754.2213,
        "2017-10-17": 5595.235,
        "2017-10-18": 5572.1988,
        "2017-10-19": 5699.5838,
        "2017-10-20": 5984.0863,
        "2017-10-21": 6013.2288,
        "2017-10-22": 5984.9563,
        "2017-10-23": 5895.2988,
        "2017-10-24": 5518.85,
        "2017-10-25": 5733.9038,
        "2017-10-26": 5888.145,
        "2017-10-27": 5767.68,
        "2017-10-28": 5732.825,
        "2017-10-29": 6140.5313,
        "2017-10-30": 6121.8,
        "2017-10-31": 6447.6675
    },
        "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index. BPI value data returned as USD.",
        "time": {
        "updated": "Nov 1, 2017 13:49:57 UTC",
        "updatedISO": "2017-11-01T13:49:57+00:00"
    }
}
```

into a hashmap - preferably `Map<Date, Double>` but `Map<String, String>` will do as well (then I would have to process it later on). I read somewhere how to convert json arrays to java arrays but since the desired array is wrapped in the  `bpi` sub field I dont know how to access it. Could you please help me with that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward with Jackson. First define a class to hold the values:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo {

    private Map<LocalDate, Double> bpi;

    // Getters and setters ommited
}
```

Then read your JSON string:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
```

---

Alternatively you can use:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json).get("bpi");

ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<Map<LocalDate, Double>>() {});
Map<LocalDate, Double> bpi = reader.readValue(node);
```

---

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) support comes from the [`jackson-datatype-jsr310`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) module.

Add the following dependency you project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And then register the [`JavaTimeModule`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jsr310/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) in your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance:

```java
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

If you prefer to use [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instead of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), then you don't need any to add any dependency and you don't need to register any module either. Just use [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instead of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) in the above examples. However I advise you to use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead.

Comment: And jackson also takes care about the conversion from `String` to `Date` / `LocalDate`?

Comment: @milkpirate Yes. See my updated answer. The `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency is required.